# How to disable lsp server syntax highlighting?

Tags: neovim, syntax-highlighting, lsp

I found out that my lsp servers is somehow adding this ugly highlighting to my code (this happened after I updated my Homebrew for some reason), here are before and after pics:

[image]
[image]

Here is my lsp server setup:

```
  local lspconfig = require('lspconfig')
  local navbuddy = require('nvim-navbuddy')
  local servers = { 'tsserver', 'eslint', 'bashls','jsonls'} 

  for _, lsp in ipairs(servers) do
      lspconfig[lsp].setup {
          capabilities = capabilities,
          -- on_attach = on_attach,
          flags = lsp_flags,
          on_attach = function(client, bufnr)
            navbuddy.attach(client, bufnr)
            vim.keymap.set('n', 'gd', vim.lsp.buf.definition, bufopts)
            vim.keymap.set('n', 'gv', function() 
                    vim.cmd([[
                        vsplit
                        ]])
                        vim.lsp.buf.definition()
            end, bufopts)
            vim.keymap.set('n', 'gl', vim.diagnostic.open_float, opts)
          end
      }
  end
```

How do I prevent it from doing this?

## What I have already tried but didn't work:

- disabling diagnostics:
  `vim.diagnostic.disable()`
- [disabling](https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/109vgtl/how_to_disable_highlight_from_lsp/) syntax higlight: `client.server_capabilities.semanticTokensProvider = nil`

Comment: You asked the same question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77410457/how-to-disable-lsp-server-syntax-highlighting Please don't crosspost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got solved by putting this in my `.config/nvim/init.vim`

```
  vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("LspAttach", {
  callback = function(args)
    local client = vim.lsp.get_client_by_id(args.data.client_id)
    client.server_capabilities.semanticTokensProvider = nil
  end,
});
```