# How to disable semantic tokens for telescope?

Tags: neovim, lsp, plugin-telescope

I had semantic tokens automatically applied by my LSP, but I was able to [disable](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/43428/how-to-disable-lsp-server-syntax-highlighting) it using this code:

```
  callback = function(args)
    local client = vim.lsp.get_client_by_id(args.data.client_id)
    client.server_capabilities.semanticTokensProvider = nil
  end,
});
```

However, now my telescope search has that same semantic token applied. How do I disable it as well for telescope?